# How well evolution is supported by experts? Are there acceptable scientific objection to evolution?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, philosophy-of-science

There are people in internet , with professional sounding voice , who claim that evolution is not scientifically possible (such as there is not enough time for evolution, or modern genetics has disproved it and what not!) or not even well supported in the scientific community. Here in Bangladesh, with a fundamentalist population, we are not even thought evolution that well, teachers avoid that and recently evolution has been forcefully removed from government textbooks. (So forgive my question is dumb) What will expert say? I am confused.

Comment: This is such a broad question that it's hard to know where to start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_support_for_evolution ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_common_descent

Comment: Experts say that evolution is the only scientifically valid and accepted theory that accounts for our observations of the biological world. The Berkeley [Understanding Evolution](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/) website is a great resource for learning about evolution.

Comment: See also: [Alternative models to natural selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_Darwinian_evolution), but you'll find that none of them have any traction in terms of superiority of explanatory power or consistency with the known observables. They're pre-scientific or non-scientific in approach.

Comment: As a problem in biology (the evidence for evolution) this is too broad a question for this site, as has already been said. Taken at face value, this is a question about scientists, not biology, and not appropriate for this site. I therefore think the question should be closed. But, to be kind: Regardless of whether they are right or wrong, almost all biological scientists employed in reputable universities ("experts") do not question evolution and regard the question as settled 100 years ago. It is the context in which the subject is viewed and nobody would waste time even discussing it.

Comment: the stated clearly series has some really good basic introductions to evolution. https://www.youtube.com/user/sciencestatedclearly

Comment: Those theorists are unscientific, because they trust scientific medecine for i.e. a paternity test, for a crime test, and do not trust the same science for i.e. species proximity test. They are unscientific because they don't trust fossils i.e. of hominids, early mammals, birds with teeth, and the 100% verified transition from lizards to mammals recorded in the sedimentary photographing process. In the USA the origin of species is doubted by 40% as well. There are many other logical certainties pseudscientists must deny to refute origin of species.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I agree with the comment: "As a problem in biology (the evidence for evolution) this is too broad a question for this site, as has already been said. Taken at face value, this is a question about scientists, not biology, and not appropriate for this site."

Answer (score 4):

It's a fact.

Natural selection, adaptation and genetic changes have been observed and documented [several times](https://www.cell.com/trends/ecology-evolution/fulltext/S0169-5347(07)00286-8?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0169534707002868%3Fshowall%3Dtrue).

But in the end, it's not about who's right, but, who has the better explanation to describe what we observe in our world.

Evolutionist denyers will have an **extremely hard time** explaining ...

- ... the appearance of [atavisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atavism)
- ... why humans share 98% of their DNA with chimpanzees
- ... why humans share 50% of their DNA with fruit flies
- ... why every living being (including bacteria) share the identical genetic code (genetic code = why the DNA sequence "GCC" will add Alanine to proteins, while "GTC" adds "Valine", etc.)
- ... the evidence described in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3GagfbA2vo)

There are no explanations that explains all that without assuming that all living beings are somehow related with another, since that's how genetic information is passed on. That's why it is considered a fact that every lifeform shares a common ancestor.

Comment: Thanks. But they have "explanation" of any problem , you know that.

Comment: @Zeesan: These 'explanations' are either based on misunderstandings, religious agenda, or other things. They are not based observing nature. Because that's what you gotta do: Observe nature. Those people that want to tear out evolution pages out of school books have NOT sat in the woods and watched birds through binoculars for months. Because that's actual work. Quick 'explanations' are lazy, but doing the right thing takes hard work. And scientists do that work, because they're crazy enough to well.. doing things like watch birds for months/years/decades or inventing DNA sequencing...

Comment: if dna is accepted as evidence in criminal cases in your country you can be pretty sure they know about evolution.